# apply custom-made function to column pairs and create summary table

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data with ratings on many parameters by two different raters; here are shown just a snippet of ratings on three same-prefix parameters (e.g. `DH` and `DH_ptak`):

```
df <- structure(list(DH = c(0, 1, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
                     DH_ptak = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
                     SZ = c(1, 1, NA, NA, NA, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1), 
                     SZ_ptak = c(1, 1, NA, NA, NA, 1, 0, NA, 1, 1), 
                     RM = c(0, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, 1, NA), 
                     RM_ptak = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, 0, 1, NA, 1)), 
                row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

For each parameter I want to compare the two ratings columns. I use this function to find **different** ratings:

```
compare_fun <- function(c1, c2){
  case_when(is.na(c1) & is.na(c2) ~ 0, 
            is.na(c1) | is.na(c2) ~ 1, 
            c1 != c2 ~ 1, 
            TRUE ~ 0)
}
```

I can use this function to `sum` the differences and compute an agreement percentage `agree_pct`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(diff = compare_fun(DH, DH_ptak)) %>%
  summarise(sum = sum(diff),
            agree_pct = (nrow(df)-sum)/nrow(df)*100)
  sum agree_pct
1   2        80
```

The problem is that I have multiple parameters. How can I compute for all ratings-column pairs the respective `sum` and `agree_pct` in one go, ideally, to obtain a table like this:

```
   sum agree_pct
DH   2        80
SZ   3        70
RM   5        50
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I would do. It mostly involves pivoting the data a few times. First I make a column from row names so that I can use this to keep all the rows straight, then I go from wide to long with `pivot_longer`. I `separate` the column names to delineate between the two reviewers and assign them the names "grp1" and "grp2". Then I `pivot_wider` so that you have 2 columns, one for each reviewer. Lastly I apply your function across all the data, group by the variable of interest and summarize the data.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  rownames_to_column("col") %>%
  pivot_longer( -col) %>%
  separate(name, into = c("var", "tmp"), sep = "_") %>%
  mutate(grp = ifelse(is.na(tmp), "grp1", "grp2")) %>%
  select(col, var, value, grp) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = grp, values_from = value) %>%
  mutate(diff = compare_fun(grp1, grp2)) %>%
  group_by(var) %>%
  summarise(sum = sum(diff),
            agree_pct = (nrow(df)-sum)/nrow(df)*100)

#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   var     sum agree_pct
#>   <chr> <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1 DH        2        80
#> 2 RM        5        50
#> 3 SZ        3        70
```

Comment: Cool, straightforward solution!